# unable to display collection values using jinja2 in flask

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, pymongo

I'm a beginner in pymongo and flask and I am using a jinja 2  html template to print document fields form a collection . I have a movies collection where an instance of a movie is like :

```
movie = {"title" : "Hobbit" , "year":"2013" , "actors": ["Legolas" , "Gandalf"] ,"plot": "some plot"}
```

I use a flask endpoint to get all movies where a specific actor has played and then I pass the list of movies using render template to jinja2 to print the values of each document . However I get an empty page instead of the values of each movie .

My template to display every document in the collection :

```html
<body>

//the logout link only shows up
<a href = "{{url_for('logout')}}"> Logout </a>
    
{% for document in movie %}
    <fieldset>
        <h2>Title  : {{document.title}}</h2>
        <h2>Published   : {{document.year}}</h2>
        <h2>Plot  : {{document.plot}}</h2>
        
        <h2>Actors :</h2>
         {% for actor in document.actors%}
            <li> {{actor}} </li>
         {% endfor%} 
    </fieldset> 
    

{% endfor %}



</body>
```

My flask endpoint :

```
@app.route('/findmoviefromactor' , methods = ['GET' , 'POST'])
def find_movie_from_actor():
    if 'Email' in session and 'User' in session:
        user = session['User']
        email = session['Email']
        if request.method=='POST':
            #find all movies where a specific actor is playing 
            movie_list = movies.find( {"actors": {"$in": [ request.form['actor'] ] } } )
            if movie_list !=None:
                for tainia in movie_list:
                    print(tainia['title']) #print each movie title
                #pass the movie list to the render template 
                return render_template('movie_details.html' , movie = movie_list)

        return render_template('movie-actor.html') 
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

So when I pass the movie list I just get an empty page with the logout link instead of  the list of movies . I would appreciate your help with guiding me through this task . Thank you in advance .

Comment: Are you able to print the values?

Comment: @ngShravil.py The problem was with mongodb compass it seems .  The code wouldn't work with movies I inserted with compass but worked for movies I inserted with flask endpoints . I don't understand however why that happens